# Why Z has to be 2-dimensional for 3d plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot 3d `Surface plots` using code from [this site](http://jeffskinnerbox.me/notebooks/matplotlib-2d-and-3d-plotting-in-ipython.html) using  matplotlib:

X,Y and Z are obtained as below:

```
from math import pi
from numpy import cos, meshgrid
alpha = 0.7
phi_ext = 2 * pi * 0.5

def flux_qubit_potential(phi_m, phi_p):
    return 2 + alpha - 2 * cos(phi_p)*cos(phi_m) - alpha * cos(phi_ext - 2*phi_p)

phi_m = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
phi_p = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
X,Y = meshgrid(phi_p, phi_m)
Z = flux_qubit_potential(X, Y).T
```

And 3d plotting is done with following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))

# `ax` is a 3D-aware axis instance, because of the projection='3d' keyword argument to add_subplot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')

p = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=4, cstride=4, linewidth=0)

# surface_plot with color grading and color bar
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
p = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
cb = fig.colorbar(p, shrink=0.5)
```

However, if I replace X,Y and Z by my x,y,z 3d data (sample give below), there is an error that `Z has to be 2 dimensional`. How can I plot with usual x,y,z values, as following:

```
   x   y   z
0  12  0  0.1
1  13  1  0.8
2  14  3  1.0
3  16  4  1.2
4  18  4  0.7
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'my x,y,z 3d data'? There is no reference to any such thing anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have added a sample of my data above.

Comment: Concerning the "why?", [Why does pyplot.contour() require Z to be a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045921/why-does-pyplot-contour-require-z-to-be-a-2d-array).  I would be very much inclined to close this as duplicate of [Simplest way to plot 3d surface given 3d points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423601/simplest-way-to-plot-3d-surface-given-3d-points) unless the question makes clear why it isn't.

Comment: @rnso The link in your question is dead.

Comment: The site must have been removed. The code is already there in the question.

Answer (score 6):

This is because, in my understanding, to draw a surface you need to form a [polygon mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh). To draw a 3d surface, you need to have small squares, for example, on the xy-plane and then have 1 corresponding z value for all the x-y points. The smaller the area of the square means finer mesh-grid and better resolution(smooth-looking surface.) Now if you have an arbitrary set of xyz points, how matplotlib can determine which surface to draw. That is why a mesh is required. You can of course plot 3d [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html) or [line plots](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#line-plots) with your data.

Comment: Is there any way I can plot x,y,z values as a mesh, wireframe or surface?

Comment: Difficult because you can then, in theory, have 2 data points and could plot a surface which will have the same problem when you try to interpolate. This is essentially an interpolation in 3d. So you will then have a non-smooth surface with not a nice triangulation(or any tessellation) . Anyway you can do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423601/simplest-way-to-plot-3d-surface-given-3d-points ( the 2nd answer)

Comment: check this for the doc: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=trisurf#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) you will find that `x`, `y` and `z` need to a 2D array. For the coordinates `x` and `y` you will need to use `numpy.meshgrid` as you show in the first piece of code. This creates a 2D array for each coordinate where `x` and `y` are constant along the other direction and vary on its own direction.

With respect to `z`, this also needs to be a 2D array since `Axes3D.surface_plot` **maps** each element of the 2D array `z` with the 2D grid defined by `x` and `y`.

Hence, when you use your own `x`, `y` and `z` make sure that you use `numpy.meshgrid` for `x` and `y` and, then,  define z = f(x,y) (e.g. the function `flux_qubit_potential` you show).

**Edit**:

After OP's comment, is clear that the desired output is a plot where the function `g` is g = f(x,y,z). This would mean that `g` is a 3D array in the end. To do this in terms of iso-surfaces have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030098/how-to-display-a-3d-plot-of-a-3d-array-isosurface-in-matplotlib-mplot3d-or-simil).

Comment: By this approach, I will not be using my z values. How do I incorporate my z values?

Comment: So is `z` a coordinate? The code you show is to plot z = f(x,y). Not a function, say `g` to which is g = f(x,y,z).

Comment: No, in my data, z is value along z-axis (just as x and y are values for corresponding axes).

Comment: Ok, then you need another function, not `Axes3D.surface_plot`. Give me a sec and I will point you on the right direction.