# 1 axis does not work correctly in 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

the value on y-axis does not change in my plot if I define my function outside `ax.plot_wireframe()`.
It is the problem of my real function which longer.

```
import pandas
import numpy
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # <--- This is important for 3d plotting 

a = numpy.linspace(1,10,10)  # x axis
b = numpy.linspace(1,10,10)  # y axis
R = a+b   #model function, real function is longer
z = R
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
a,b = numpy.meshgrid(a,b)
#ax.plot_wireframe(a,b,a+b, color='b') #correct
#ax.plot_wireframe(a,b,z, color='b') #wrong
ax.plot_wireframe(a,b,R, color='b') #wrong
ax.set_title('surface');
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
```

Here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the matplotlib documentation regarding [3D wireframe plots](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots). The x, y and z values need to be 2-dimensional. Explanations for this are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289048/why-are-the-arguments-to-matplotlibs-plot-wireframe-two-dimensional-arrays) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246874/why-z-has-to-be-2-dimensional-for-3d-plotting-in-matplotlib). This is also the reason for the line

```
a,b = numpy.meshgrid(a,b)
```

in your code. It creates a 10x10 2D array for both 1D inputs. In the next lines you call the wireframe method with `a+b` for the z values. Hence, the z values are calculated in place and the result is again a 10x10 2D array. The reason why you get the "wrong" graph with the variables `R or z` is that they are calculated **before** `a and b` are turned into their respective 2D meshgrids. If you define `R or z` after the line containing `numpy.meshgrid` it works fine.

```
import pandas
import numpy
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # <--- This is important for 3d plotting 

a = numpy.linspace(1,10,10)  # x axis
b = numpy.linspace(1,10,10)  # y axis

R = a+b   #not working
z = R     #not working

def f(x,y): 
    return x+y

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
a,b = numpy.meshgrid(a,b)

Z = f(a,b)#working
R = a+b   #working
z = R     #working

#ax.plot_wireframe(a,b,a+b, color='b') #
#ax.plot_wireframe(a,b,Z, color='b') #
ax.plot_wireframe(a,b,R, color='b') #
ax.set_title('surface');
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
```

So the short answer is: `numpy.meshgrid` changes your variables a and b and your are basically doing your calculations with different `a`s and `b`s

Comment: yeah, I have just realized this. thanks. I accepted your answer.