# How do I get isobaric relative humidity data into 2D array form?

Tags: python-xarray, metpy

I'm trying to create a contour plot of relative humidity at a constant pressure level (500hPa) similar to that in the [MetPy xarray tutorial](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/tutorials/xarray_tutorial.html). I have acquired data using the Siphon package and have parsed it into an array that *seems* to be 2-D with time and height fixed and latitude/longitude varying:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'relative_humidity' (time: 1, lat: 141, lon: 121)>
array([[[100. , 100. , ...,  48.5,  48.1],
        [100. , 100. , ...,  42.8,  41.1],
        ...,
        [  9.5,   9.4, ...,  20.7,  18.7],
        [  9.5,   9.9, ...,  23.8,  21.1]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    reftime   (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-03-24T12:00:00
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-03-24T18:00:00
    isobaric  float32 50000.0
  * lat       (lat) float32 55.0 54.75 54.5 54.25 54.0 ... 20.75 20.5 20.25 20.0
  * lon       (lon) float32 270.0 270.25 270.5 270.75 ... 299.5 299.75 300.0
    crs       object Projection: latitude_longitude
```

To get this array, I used the code:

```
data = ncss.get_data(query)

#Parse data using MetPy
ds = xr.open_dataset(NetCDF4DataStore(data))
data = ds.metpy.parse_cf()

#Rename variables to useful things
data = data.rename({
    'Vertical_velocity_pressure_isobaric': 'omega',
    'Relative_humidity_isobaric': 'relative_humidity',
    'Temperature_isobaric': 'temperature',
    'u-component_of_wind_isobaric': 'u',
    'v-component_of_wind_isobaric': 'v',
    'Geopotential_height_isobaric': 'height'
})

#Get data specific to 500mb
zH5 = data['height'].metpy.sel(vertical=850 * units.hPa)
zH5_crs = zH5.metpy.cartopy_crs

#Define coordinates
vertical, = data['temperature'].metpy.coordinates('vertical')
time = data['temperature'].metpy.time
x, y = data['height'].metpy.coordinates('x', 'y')
lat, lon = xr.broadcast(y, x)

#Create relative humidity array
rel_hum = data['relative_humidity'].metpy.sel(vertical=500*units.hPa)
```

However, when I go to plot RH as filled contours:

```
rh = ax.contourf(x, y, rel_hum, levels=[70, 80, 90, 100], colors=['#99ff00', '#00ff00', '#00cc00'])
```

I get an error message:

```
TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 3D
```

After reading [another SO post about a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045921/why-does-pyplot-contour-require-z-to-be-a-2d-array), I understand *why* the third parameter of the contour function needs to be a 2-D array, but I'm not sure why my procedure here (which very closely mimics the [xarray tutorial code from the MetPy docs](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/tutorials/xarray_tutorial.html)) doesn't produce such an array capable of being plotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while it seems like your data are 2D since you only have a single time, based on this output:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'relative_humidity' (time: 1, lat: 141, lon: 121)>
```

the data are still considered 3D since you still have a dimension of time (even though it's a size of 1). One way to this is by modifying your call to `.sel` to select a particular time (or add another call to `.sel` to do this).

My preferred way to solve this is by using a call to `.squeeze()`. `squeeze()` is a method to remove all size-1 dimensions, solving this very frequent problem of having some extraneous dimensions (that don't actually add to the total number of elements in an array):

```
rel_hum = data['relative_humidity'].metpy.sel(vertical=500*units.hPa).squeeze()
```

This also has the effect that if you really do have 3D data, it won't change the shape. Depending on your application, this may or may not be a good thing. (If it's bad, using `.sel` to select a time is a better option.)