# How to format data for matplotlib contour

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am experimenting with gradient descent and want to plot a contour of the gradient given independent variables x and y.

The optimization objective is to estimate a point given only a list of points and the distances to each of those points. I have a list of vectors of form `[(x_1, y_1, d_1), ..., (x_n, y_n, d_n)]` where `d_i` is the measured distance from the point to be estimated to the point `(x_i, y_i)`, and I have a function `g(x, y)` that returns the gradient at the point `(x, y)`. (The function `g(x, y)` uses the training vectors to calculate the gradient.)

The gradient descent algorithm works fine and arrives at a close estimate to the actual point coordinates. I want now to visualize the gradient as a contour map. I have the following for x and y values:

```
xlist = np.linspace(min([v[0] for v in vectors])-1, max([v[0] for v in vectors])+1, 100)
ylist = np.linspace(min([v[1] for v in vectors])-1, max([v[1] for v in vectors])+1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
```

But now I need a `Z` value that maps each pair of coordinates in the grid mesh to `g(x, y)`, and it needs to be the correct shape for the matplotlib contour plot. The examples I have seen have been useless because they all simply multiplied the x and y arrays to generate z values (which obviously will not work in this case), and all the tips, tricks, and SO answers I have encountered ultimately did not help.

How do I use my custom function `g(x, y)` to create the 2D `Z` array necessary for constructing a valid contour plot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546471/7758804

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney the solution was to use `zlist = [f(x,y) for x, y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))]` and `Z = np.reshape(zlist, X.shape)`. I'll write an answer explaining what I figured out after I get some computer stability issues sorted. (BSODs suck.)